# Scale matplotlib text relative to axes/axes limits/circle in drawing

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a circle in matplotlib, and subsequently add a label. However, I cannot get the label size to be correct.
I create a circle patches using `matplotlib.patches.Circle`. I can properly scale the circle compared to the current axis by adding the `radius` variable when I call the circle.

To create the text in the circle, I use `axis.text()`. This function allows me to set the fontsize directly. To scale the fontsize with the radius, I input `fontsize=int(circle_radius * base_fontsize)`, where `base_fontsize` is cherry picked to be the 'correct' size.

This all works more or less, as is shown in the following code snippet:

```
from matplotlib import patches

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# To size the label, we multiply a base fontsize by the node radius
base_fontsize = 50

# Use tex for the labels?
usetex = True

# figsize_multiplier to evenly scale the picture
figsize_multiplier = 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (figsize_multiplier*2,figsize_multiplier*1))

# Create axes for left and right plot
axis1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
plt.axis('off') # Cleaner picture
axis2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
plt.axis('off') # Cleaner picture

axis1.set(xlim=[-1,1], ylim=[-1,1], aspect=1) # Force the aspect ratio to be 1:1
axis2.set(xlim=[-1,1], ylim=[-1,1], aspect=1) # Force the aspect ratio to be 1:1

## Create a smaller circle on the left
small_radius = 0.4
smallcircle = patches.Circle(xy = (0,0), radius = small_radius, facecolor = 'g',
                             edgecolor = 'k', linewidth = 5 * small_radius)
# Add the circle to the plot
axis1.add_patch(smallcircle)

# Create label in small circle
axis1.text(x = 0, y = 0, s = '$\\mathrm{left}$', fontsize=int(base_fontsize*small_radius),
          ha="center", va="center", usetex = usetex, color = 'k')

## Create a bigger circle on the right
big_radius = 0.8
bigcircle = patches.Circle(xy = (0,0), radius = big_radius, facecolor = 'r',
                            edgecolor = 'k', linewidth = 5 * big_radius)
# Add to plot
axis2.add_patch(bigcircle)

# Create label in big circle
axis2.text(x = 0, y = 0, s = '$\\mathrm{right}$', fontsize=int(base_fontsize*big_radius),
          ha="center", va="center", usetex = usetex, color = 'k')
```

which outputs the following picture (screenshotted so low resolution):

[image: small version]

however, when I now change the `figsize_multiplier` to `4` to get a larger picture, the labels don't get scaled:

[image]

What is a better way of scaling the label fontsize?

I tried scaling the fontsize with the node radius, but the scaling doesn't work as intended. The fontsize is fixed/relative to the figure size, but I control over the text relative to the axis or drawing in the axis.